# How to import enum using path alias in Svelte Kit?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

## The Problem

I cannot import an enum from a `.ts` file into a `__layout.svelte` component using a path alias.

I have an interface that I can export and use without problem through the path alias. Importing an enum throws an error: `Cannot find module...`

However, importing the enum using a relative path (`../types/types-load-menu-paths`) works fine.

**Why am I encountering issues using path aliases?**

I also encounter a similar problem with aliasing when trying to import from the `src` directory. E.g., I have an `app.css` file I cannot reference.

### Setup

- I have a file named `types-load-menu-path.ts` with an enum (MenuOrder) and an interface (Paths)
- I import them into a `__layout.svelte` component using a path alias: `$types`
- The interface is imported using `import type { Paths } from '$types/types-load-menu-paths';`
- The enum is imported using `import { MenuOrder } from '$types/types-load-menu-paths';` otherwise I get an error: `'MenuOrder' cannot be used as a value because it was imported using 'import type'`

#### `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "es2020",
        "lib": ["es2020", "DOM"],
        "target": "esnext",
        "strict": true,
        /**
            svelte-preprocess cannot figure out whether you have a value or a type, so tell TypeScript
            to enforce using \`import type\` instead of \`import\` for Types.
            */
        "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "paths": {
            "$lib": ["src/lib"],
            "$lib/*": ["src/lib/*"],
            "$src/*": ["src/*"],
            "$components/*": ["src/lib/components/*"],
            "$stores/*": ["src/lib/stores/*"],
            "$templates/*": ["src/lib/templates/*"],
            "$utils/*": ["src/lib/utils/*"],
            "$types/*": ["src/types/*"],
            "$styles/*": ["src/styles/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.svelte", "src/**/*.css"]
}
```

#### `svelte.config.js`

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import path from 'path'; 

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: [
        preprocess({
            postcss: true
        })
    ],

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    },

    vite: { 
        resolve: { 
            alias: { 
                "$src": path.resolve('./src/*'),
                "$lib": path.resolve('./src/lib/*'),
                "$components": path.resolve('./src/lib/components/*'),
                "$stores": path.resolve('./src/lib/stores/*'),
                "$templates": path.resolve('./src/lib/templates/*'),
                "$utils": path.resolve('./src/lib/utils/*'),
                "$types": path.resolve('./src/types/*'),
                "$styles": path.resolve('./src/styles'),
            }
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

#### `types-load-menu-paths.ts`

```
export enum MenuOrder {
    HOME,
    ABOUT,
    BLOG,
}

export interface Paths {
    path: string;
    title: string;
    order: MenuOrder;
}
```

#### `__layout.svelte`

```
<script context="module" lang="ts">

    ...

    import type { Paths } from '$types/types-load-menu-paths';
    import { MenuOrder } from '../types/types-load-menu-paths';
    
    ...

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

## A Solution

Inside the `svelte.config.js`:

- Move `vite.resolve.alias...` inside `kit`:
- Remove trailing `*` in `resolve`; e.g. `$components: resolve('./src/lib/components/*')` should be `$components: resolve('./src/lib/components/')`

If the `*` is not removed, an SSR error is thrown:

`Error: failed to load module for ssr: /src/lib/components/*/DefaultLayout/Header.svelte`

### `svelte.config.js`

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import { resolve } from 'path';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: [
        preprocess({
            postcss: true
        })
    ],

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        // moved vite.resolve.alias... inside kit and removed path ../* 
        vite: {
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    $src: resolve('./src/'),
                    $lib: resolve('./src/lib/'),
                    $components: resolve('./src/lib/components/'),
                    $stores: resolve('./src/lib/stores/'),
                    $templates: resolve('./src/lib/templates/'),
                    $utils: resolve('./src/lib/utils/'),
                    $types: resolve('./src/types/'),
                    $styles: resolve('./src/styles')
                }
            }
        }
    },
};

export default config;
```

More information can be found in the [SvelteKIT FAQ](https://kit.svelte.dev/faq#aliases).

Comment: Good sleuthing, I completely missed the `vite` placement issue.

Comment: does not work as of 2023-03-08